# What's the difference between 有 (you) and 的?

Tags: simplified-characters

They both means have.

In the song https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk3VQoAKMUI

有 is used first in ni wen wo ai ni you duo sen.

Latter it's followed by wo de qing ye sen

Why use 有 and then use 的?

Comment: 的 doesn't mean 'have' . It is either a possessive marker, similar to ['s]  or an adjectival marker that denotes a phrase as an adjective phrase

Comment: No offense but what medium(s) are you using to learn Chinese?

Comment: This. What do you mean by medium

Answer (score 1):

[有](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9C%89) is a verb which means "to have":

> I **have** a glass of water
>   我**有**一杯水
>   <sub>Wǒ **yǒu** yī bēi shuǐ</sub>

的 is *not a verb*, and is referred to as a [possessive particle](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Structural_particle_%22de%22#.E7.9A.84_.28de.29_Before_Nouns).  For example it changes [我](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%88%91) ("me") into [我的](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%88%91%E7%9A%84) ("mine").

> **My** name is Emily
>   **我的**名字是Emily
>   <sub>**Wǒ de** míngzì shì Emily</sub>

的 is also used after adjectives:

> **red** apple
>   **红色的**苹果
>   <sub>**hóngsè de** píngguǒ</sub>

---

In songs, a lot of poetic license is used to maintain rhythm.  So they're often not a normal way of speaking.  In the following case there's probably a few ways of parsing the grammar.  I interpret it as a kind of [topic-comment sentence](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Topic-comment_sentences):

> You ask: "I love you" **has** how much depth?
>   你问我爱你**有**多深
>   <sub>Nǐ wèn wǒ ài nǐ **yǒu** duō shēn</sub>

It would be incorrect here to use 的 in place of 有, as it would change the preceding [你](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BD%A0) ("you") into [你的](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BD%A0%E7%9A%84) ("your").

In the following, the possessive particle 的 turns 我 ("me") into 我的 ("mine"):

> **My** emotions [are] also real
>   **我的**情也真
>   <sub>**Wǒ de** qíng yě zhēn</sub>